# Is there a tool to generate MVC code in C#?

Tags: c#, code-generation

I was working on a project with a colleague and went out for lunch one day. Given that we only spent a few days doing design and no coding, I was surprised to find out that after lunch, he had over 40 files completed (various classes, interfaces, DTOs, etc). 
He told me he is just a fast typist but I need to know the real deal. He hasn't been able to sustain that kind of productivity just the initial skeletal code but still, any ideas how he did this?

Answer (score 1):

The standard new project for MVC already has controllers for Home and Account, as well as tests generated. If he then used Entity Framework to generate the data layer, then you could produce a lot of code extremely quickly.